# How to make 100% table height work with min-height parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Seems a simple problem but I can't get an inner div to be 100% height to the parent div set with min-height 70vh. I want the table inside to be 100% height and content vertically aligned. It works if I set 70vh for the parents height but this does not allow for more content. Fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/RustyBadRobot/zgesx50L/8/

```
.hero-row {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  min-height: 70vh;
  height: 70vh; /* This makes it work but if content goes over fails to expand */
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.centrize {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this by having the child of the element inherit the same `min-height: 70vh`.
So, add `min-height: inherit` to the first child element and it should work as expected.

```
.centrize {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: inherit;
}
```